# Selcting Random queries from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, random, foreign-keys

Am trying to SELECT a specific number of ***Random*** questions from the table

Something like 3 random questions from  questions table which are tagged as group_1 and two from group_3

This is my SQL command

```
SELECT
    questions.qid,
    tags.tag
FROM
    tag_dir tag_dir
JOIN questions ON questions.qid = tag_dir.qid
JOIN tags ON tags.id = tag_dir.tag_id
WHERE tags.id having 1 and 2
LIMIT 0,10
```

But I don't know how to get a ***specific number of Random results***

Here is my table structure
[image: image description here]

Here is my [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i3MM7XGvbfExGLZNcoC4Az/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help if you can use UNIONs to get the random result set for each tag and then relate the other tables.

```
SELECT
    questions.qid,
    tags.tag
FROM
    (
        (SELECT * from tag_dir where tag_id=1 order by rand() LIMIT 3) 
        UNION 
        (SELECT * from tag_dir where tag_id=2 order by rand() LIMIT 2)
   )  tq
   JOIN questions ON questions.qid = tq.qid
   JOIN tags ON tags.id = tq.tag_id
```

You can add as many in the UNION as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns 5 random results. You can change the number of results by modifying the `LIMIT` clause.

```
SELECT questions.qid, tags.tag 
    FROM tag_dir tag_dir 
JOIN questions ON questions.qid = tag_dir.qid 
JOIN tags ON tags.id = tag_dir.tag_id 
WHERE tags.id having 1 and 2
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 5;
```

[Reference](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/select-random-records-database-table.aspx)